# Compare two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays named ***rows and contacts***.

The first array ***rows*** is like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => email@gmail.com
    [1] => test@gmail.com
    [2] => tester@gmail.com
    [3] => vin@gmail.com
)
```

The second array ***contacts*** is as :

```
Array
(
    [test@gmail.com] => test@gmail.com
    [ram@gmail.com] => Ram
    [vin@gmail.com] => Vinay
    [man_test@yahoo.com] => Manoj
    [homan@rediffmail.com] => Homan
)
```

What I want is the ***contacts*** array to be as :

```
Array
    (
        [ram@gmail.com] => Ram
        [man_test@yahoo.com] => Manoj
        [homan@rediffmail.com] => Homan
    )
```

### Edit

I tried some functions like **array_diff(), array_keys()** etc. but they are not giving me the desired output, may be I am not able to use them correctly....!

I don't want to use loop for this purpose because the given arrays are only sample data but in real they are very huge.

Please help.....

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: So you want to remove all the entries in contacts that are found in rows? Is that correct?

Comment: I am *assuming* the `$contact` array should be the `$contacts` array with emails in `$rows` removed, since that matches the example. Why you wouldn't simply write that when asking someone to write code for you is beyond me. And why a "PHP developer" still needs help with something like loops and arrays is a big question mark too.

Comment: @Laurent : yes you are right.

Comment: I edited the question, please have a look again.....

Comment: For your 2nd edit "I don't want to use a loop", any array function you use is still going to be implemented with a loop. You can't avoid comparing the entries... that would be impossible. Don't ask for things computers cannot do. The fancy answer using multiple array functions is going to do *more* work than the simple loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
$contacts = array_diff_key($contacts, array_flip($rows));
```

Comment: Sorry, but not giving the desired output.

Comment: @Pushpendra: It does for me: http://codepad.org/bu3juNj1 . I think your data is not correct and the email addresses might have leading or trailing white spaces.

Comment: @Pushpendra, if this doesn't give you the answer you're looking for then your question is incorrectly stated.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($contacts as $email => $name) {
  if (!in_array($email, $rows)) {
    $contact[$email] = $name;
  }
}
```

The new array is `$contact`, not `$contacts`, as your question asked for before you edited it.

Comment: You are doing the opposite of what he's asking - you are adding contacts when he wants to remove those found in rows.

Comment: @Pushpendra No it does not. I have tested it. The new array is `$contact` not `$contacts` which is what your question originally asked for the result to be called before you edited it.

Comment: @Laurent That is what this does. Note the `!` negation operator: **is not in array $rows**. It builds a new array `$contact` containing only the desired results. This is the variable he asked for before editing his question.

Comment: @Pushpendra: No it does not: http://codepad.org/TgFL8P5K Make sure your data is correct and it does not contain any leading or trailing white spaces.

Comment: @Dan : Sorry but I have tested it again and it is showing me the same duplicate row...?

Comment: @Pushpendra Did you click the link in Felix's comment? It shows the code executing and producing the correct result. What more do you want? The fact that you're saying everybody's answers don't work when they are all correct means **your data or specification is not correct**. Why are you wasting everyone's time?

Comment: @Pushpendra: We showed you ways that definitely work. So it is not a problem with the approach but with the data. We can only work with the data you showed us in your question. You have to figure out the rest on your own or update the data.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, you could do that:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {
    $s = $rows[$i];
    unset($contacts[$s]);
}
```

Comment: This destroys all of `$contacts` and does not build `$contact`.

Comment: That only removes the contacts with an email found in $rows. If the email is not in $contacts, nothing happens.

Comment: At the time of my comment, your answer simply unset the entire array, and the original question had asked for a new array `$contact` not to modify the existing array `$contacts`. I have removed my downvote.

Comment: But before answering I asked for clarifications, and I answered based on what he replied. Ok the array was incorrectly being unset (I got the unset syntax wrong, which I later fixed).

Comment: `count` beforehand: `for($i = 0, $l = count($rows); $i < $l;...)`

Answer (score 0):

As Felix Kling and Dan Grossman's answers will work on the examples you have shown, you probably have whitespace issues like newlines in your data, especially if you have extracted it from a file.  So, extending Felix's answer:

```
$contacts = array_diff_key(array_map('trim', $contacts), array_flip(array_map('trim', $rows)));
```

You could probably make it more efficient by constructing your data correctly in the first place, but this should do the trick.

http://codepad.org/RIvLbyJy

Comment: It should be `array_flip(array_map('trim',$rows))` :)